# Confusion about contents of project hosted on Google Code (GPL 2.0)

Tags: ip, open-source, licensing, definition

Can someone tell me whether an open source project with GPL 2.0 license hosted on Google Code using images/icons as resource can be used in my project commercially or personally?  I can provide attribution to author.

In simple words I want to use a certain graphic element of an open source project available under the GPL 2.0 license.  Does the license agreement cover that graphic element? Is there any Google developer forum, like the Apple developer forum, where I can pose this question?

I can't seem to find any good resources regarding my query.  Thanks for looking at my request.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing or legal issues, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274963/questions-about-licensing/274964#274964) and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139804/can-licensing-questions-ever-be-on-topic) for details, and the [help] for more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In simple words I want to use certain graphic element of open source project which include GPL 2.0 ver license. Does that graphic entity falls in license agreement?

If not explicitly stated otherwise, yes.

> Is there any Google developer forum like apple developer one where I can put question regarding this query?
>   Can you find the developers email on Google-code? Then ask him directly, maybe for the permission to use it in a different way, in combination with another license.
>
> ... can be used in my project commercially or personally?

If you use something personally, aka: without distributing it, you can use and modify GPL - code (and therefore: Images) freely at will.

Of course, for a commercial project, it is different. Then you're distributing a derived work.